# Extracting javascript info from a website

Tags: javascript, html

http://zezo.org/vor/polars.html?pro=0

I would like to make a excel sheet with the windspeed, wind angle and boat speed from this javascript interactive. i could theoretically just go through each wind speed and wind angle to get boat speed using the link above but that would take forever. Is there a way to extract this info in a faster manner? I have seen similar done before but not sure on the tech to do it. I am a very rough c#/wpf/SQl guy (self taught on the job)

Thanks!

Comment: i think node.js can help with this? anyone care to share code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [webscraping](https://www.webharvy.com/articles/what-is-web-scraping.html). There are several free tools available which will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect element you can grab the front end js file. From there you should be able to programmatically insert different values and save the outputs to whatever data structure you like.